# question about Skorokhod distance

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $D:=D([0,1], R)$ be the space of all cadlag functions defined on $[0,1]$. Now we have the known Skorokhod topology defined by: $\forall f, g\in D$

$$\rho(f,g):=\inf_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\Big\{\max\big(||f\circ \lambda-g||, ||\lambda-I||\big)\Big\}$$

where $\Lambda$ is the collection of strictly increasing functions $\lambda$ with $\lambda(0)=0$ and $\lambda(1)=1$. Here $\circ$ means the composition, $||\cdot||$ denotes the uniform norm and $I$ is the identity function. Now define two other distances $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$. Denote by $\Lambda'\subset\Lambda$ the subset of $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(1/2)=1/2$. Then define for $\forall f,g\in D$:

$$\rho_1(f,g)=\rho(f,g)+|f(1/2)-g(1/2)|$$

and

$$\rho_2(f,g):=\inf_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}\Big\{\max\big(||f\circ \lambda-g||, ||\lambda-I||\big)\Big\}$$

My question is whether there exists some $0<c<C$ such that

$$c\rho_2(f,g)\le \rho_1(f,g)\le C\rho_2(f,g),~ \forall f,g\in D$$

It is easy to see $C=2$ but I can not prove the existence of $c$. I strongly believe that the $c$ does not exist. But I can not find out a counterexample. Does someone know a counterexample? Thx for the reply!